# AR Foundation Does Not Work in Windows Builds

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

I have a Unity AR Fundation Project and my Android build works for AR Foundation. But when I build for Windows, AR Foundation does not work. Because it does not recognize the webcam.

I have reached the answer in the Android output, but I have a problem in the Windows output.

Answer (score 1):

ARFoundation is an abstraction layer for 4 mobile AR technologies:

```
ARCore XR Plugin on Android
ARKit XR Plugin on iOS
Magic Leap XR Plugin on Magic Leap
Windows XR Plugin on HoloLens
```

It does not work on Windows at all because there is no AR SDK it could even work with.
This is mentioned right at the very top of the official [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.1/manual/index.html)
Getting AR working on Windows requires other plugins altogether and depends on what AR capabilities you are looking for. E.g. plane detection, face tracking.